# Flutter how to store sharepreferances value for localization in bloc

Tags: android, flutter, bloc

i have implemented localization with bloc pattern but now I wanna store the value of language in sharepreferences so that next time if the user already selected language it will skip select language flow and  fetch it from local storage. this is my code for language state.

```
class LanguageState extends Equatable {
```

final Locale locale;
const LanguageState({required this.locale});
factory LanguageState.initial() => const LanguageState(locale: Locale('en', 'US'));

LanguageState copyWith({required Locale locale}) => LanguageState(locale: locale);

@override
// TODO: implement props
List get props => [locale];
}

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package for localization
[easylocalization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization)

you can fetch current locale value like this

```
var currentLocale = EasyLocalization.of(context)?.locale ?? 'en';
```

& store the value like this in sharedpreference

```
await SharedPref.write("local_val", //your value);
```

& use it in your condition

```
    If(local_val != null){

         //do your navigation
   }
```

Comment: i have already implemented bloc for localization, here i wanna know how to use shared preference in the bloc for initializing language if user already set language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hydrated_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc) to keep the current bloc state or make **sharedpreferences** synchronously like below .

```
//global variable of shared pref
static late SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  //making sharedPreference synchronously
  Future<void> initializeSharedPref() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
```

Call this function before calling the **runApp()** , Then where you want sharedpref instance  just call the global static variable like this

```
sharedPreferences.setString("userId", id);
```